# AWS Calculator Save & Share feature

Tags: amazon-web-services

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=52853 mentions the "Save & Share" feature.

But I couldn't find out how to "Save & Share" on http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Answer (score 9):

After doing your estimate, click the "Estimate of your Monthly Bill" tab.

There is a "Save and Share" button.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After clicking Save and Share you would be prompted to enter name and description and after that it will generate an http link which you can share.

- Kunal

Answer (score 0):

Available in the new calculator at: https://calculator.aws/#/estimate
Just click the save button on top.